# Is it possible to run a command in bash, and start another one based on the output of the 1st?

Tags: bash

I created an alias

```
alias rubyserver='ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 5000 . && open localhost:5000'
```

so as to start up a web server and then open the page that is served by the server.  But the second command won't run until the first command is finished.

Is there a way to run the command, and then start running a second one, whenever the first one has outputted a certain string?

The second command must be able to see that the first command prints out `WEBrick::HTTPServer#start`, meaning the server is already running, and before starting.

Comment: I forgot to add a comment to my edit of the question. I rephrased it from the original to focus more on the actual end goal of wanting to wait for a particular output.

Answer (score 2):

This is derived from this answer on stackoverflow.com:

- [How to pipe stdout while keeping it on screen ? (and not to a output file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677425/7365127)

Essentially,

```
one_command 2>&1 | tee >(grep -Fq keyword && other_command)
```

The `2>&1` is needed when you want to capture `stderr` output also, if you don't want that, leave it out.

---

In your case this should work:

```
ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 5000 . 2>&1 \
  | tee >(grep -Fq 'WEBrick::HTTPServer#start' && open localhost:5000)
```